# web app on mobile, pages have different dimensions

Tags: javascript, iframe

There is a behaviour I don't understand on my web app on Chrome for mobile, on my Nexus 4.

Let's say I want to open a an html ad, contained in the page view.html. The ad is 250px * 250px.

1 - If I open directly view.html in the browser: window.innerWidth = 284 and window.innerHeight = 511. The dimension of the ad looks good.

2 - Index.html is the page that opens view.html in an iframe. If I open index.html, window.innerWidth = 980 and window.innerHeight = 1305.
The iframe loads view.html but in this situation, the iframe looks too small.

I don't understand why the two pages have different dimensions ?
Thank you for your help !

Comment: You need viewport metatag on index.html page https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 0):

As @jcubic said in comment, all I needed was to add:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

in the head of index.html

Thank you

Comment: If you write html it will be rendered as html, so meta tag will be invisible, you need to mark it as code using {} button or 4 space indent.